# How to make a link to a file in angular JS

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

I am uploading files using spring boot and angular JS , I am also adding the details of the files to a table where i want to have access to the file , so i put in the html page

```
<tr ng-repeat="r in reports"  >

                                <td>{{r.id_file}}</td>
                                <td>{{r.nameOfUploader}}</td>
                                <td>{{r.dateOfUpload}}</td>
                                <td>{{r.typeOfFile}}</td>
<!--                                <td>{{r.fileName}}</td> -->
    <td><a ng-href="F:/FilesStore/{{r.id_file}}-{{r.nameOfUploader}}"/>{{r.fileName}}</a></td>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need a URL that is relative to your document root. From the browser you do not have access to the drive on the server, only to the content of document root. So it cannot find F:/

Comment: You can't link to the hard drive as you've done. You need to link to the path relative to the webserver. If your webserver runs as `localhost` then the ng-href should be `localhost/path_to_file`

Comment: As far as I know this could be possible with the Web FileSystem API.

Comment: But  when i upload the files, i store them in f:/fileStore ,  sso howa can i change my url?

Comment: `file:///` will do the trick...

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work

Comment: I wanted to downoald my files on server as you tell me and i added a folder wich name is FilesStore in the folder static  and i put in the java controller     BufferedOutputStream stream =
                        new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new  File("/FilesStore/"+d2.getFileName()))); but it gives me an error , what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

#### Store your files on a server

As some posted in the comments, from the browser you do not have access to the files on the server and to access these files you will need to "proxy" them - serve these files as static files from your web application server

**e.g.**

```
HTTP GET /static/storage/<filename>
```

will be retrieved from

```
F:/FilesStore/<filename>
```

and your link will look like

```
<a ng-href="/static/storage/{{r.id_file}}-{{r.nameOfUploader}}" />
```

### If you still want to link to direct files

i guess it's become more relevant if you and your co-workers have the same share mapping (lan-office network), then (for internal use of course) you can add `file:///` to the path which will result in opening it via the browser

```
<a ng-href="file:///F:/FilesStore/{{r.id_file}}-{{r.nameOfUploader}}" />
```

Comment: okay if i want to store them in server , i store them in tomcat or i use filezilla for ex ?

Comment: I try this way  <a ng-href="/static/storage/{{r.id_file}}-{{r.nameOfUploader}}" /> but it didn't  work

Comment: You need to configure tomcat to use `/static/...`  as static file directory

Comment: I am using spring boot so automatically he searches for the static files in the folder static , for example i am using a bootstrap template i have put it in the static folder and without any configuration ,he find the html pages